# if chain vs. exception in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am writing a reader of [DS18B20 sensors](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/software) using `subprocess.Popen` and parsing the output of a device file through `cat` command. Since the result may be unpredictable (1-wire software driver is not terribly reliable on raspberry pi) I want to make the function a bit more bulletproof, catching all the possible cases of the console output.
Essentially the question comes up to the **if chain vs. exception** question. I feel like avoiding exceptions is a good thing, so I came up with something like that:

```
def check_crc(lines):
    out = False
    if type(lines) == list:
        if len(lines) >= 1:
            if type(lines[0]) == str and type(lines[1]) == str:
                out = lines[0].strip()[-3:] == 'YES' and lines[1].find('t=') != -1
    return out
```

Is there any cleaner way of doing that using exceptions? Should I use exceptions here?

Comment: That depends on what the output you are parsing looks like when working and under error conditions. Your checks seem highly redundant, though, if you've read something from a process you don't need to check if it's a list of strings.

Comment: This really looks like a question that would be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow.  Since there's nothing actually wrong with your code, and you're looking for some opinions on how to improve it, Code Review would be the place to go.  You'll need to delete the question from Stack Overflow, and then post it to Code Review.  Make sure not to have it in both places, because cross-posting is strongly discouraged (e.g. bad for you).

Comment: A common programming idiom used in python is EAFP (https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), where you assume correct responses and handle exceptions. I try to avoid nested `if` chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely yank your first if statement. If you want your function to only accept a list, then only pass a list. For future reference, `isinstance` is preferable to `type(o) == cls`.

The second if statement should just be `if lines`.

Your third if statement could be simplified to something like `all(isinstance(line, str) for line in lines[:2])`. Again though, only calling your function with the correct argument type is preferable.

Personally, I would prefer something much simpler. Catching `IndexError`, `TypeError` and `AttributeError` should be sufficient for this:

```
def check_crc(lines):
    return lines[0].endswith("YES") and "t=" in lines[1]
```